# How can I use web.config to add parameter to domain default.asp

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am trying to add a parameter(s) to my website's home page...such as

www.myhomepage.com/param1/param2/

I know I can do this with a default.asp page -  www.myhomepage.com/default/param1/param2

but how can I hide that default and just add the parameters after the .com/ - or can't I?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't understand your issue clearly. Could you please tell me what you mean about add parameter with "default.asp page "? Do you mean you want to use web.config's url rewrite to add the parameters to special domain?Besides, if you just want to make  "www.myhomepage.com/param1/param2/" work as "www.myhomepage.com/default/param1/param2". You could directly modify the IIS's default document setting to enable the  "default.asp" as the default document.

Comment: Thank you Brando. I want the primary domain to have parameters. For example, if there is a website www.brando.com, it will by default resolve to a default or index page, albeit default.asp or index.asp  What I am after is using the url rewrite on default.asp (or index.asp) and having the url resolve WITHOUT the default (or index) in the url page, so for example it would be www.brando.com/param1/param2/  Does that make sense?